# How to set the yAxis by 5 in angular echarts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

here's the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-echarts-odv9rp?file=src/app/app.component.html

***TS***

```
xAxis = {
    type: "category",
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
  };
  yAxis = {
    type: "value",
    max: "100"
  };
  series = [
    {
      data: [23.2, 24.3, 32.2, 36.5, 32.9, 52.2, 92.1],
      type: "line",
      areaStyle: {}
    }
  ];
```

***HTML***

```
<ngx-echarts
  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"
  [xAxis]="xAxis"
  [yAxis]="yAxis"
  [series]="series">
</ngx-echarts>
```

What I'm trying to do is to set the yAxis by 5. for the example 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ... to 100.

How to set the yAxis to by 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [interval](https://www.echartsjs.com/en/option.html#yAxis.interval):

```
yAxis = {
  type: "value",
  max: "100",
  interval: 5
}
```